# Numpy installation stuck at PEP 517 wheel

Tags: python, numpy

> Background for this question: So far, I've not been able to find any satisfactory answer for my problem (as none of the solution worked in my case), so I am asking this question.

**Installing numpy (Linux)**

I've already **successfully** installed and **upgraded** `pip` and `python` to their latest version. However whenever I try to install `numpy` using `pip install numpy` command, it takes an unusual long pause while building a wheel `(PEP 517)` and my wait never gets over.

I've seen tons of solutions like installing `llvm` to support the process of building wheel, or like upgrading python and pip, and so many more, tried all of them, but so far none of them worked for me.

Dropbox [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/utmhqqvwg3t3g7s/log.txt?dl=0) of `log.txt` file, generated by:

```
pip install numpy --log log.txt
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Try updating the pip

Comment: Already tried, still not working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to find a possible solution for my problem using a GitHub repository

```
curl -LO https://its-pointless.github.io/setup-pointless-repo.sh
bash setup-pointless-repo.sh
```

After the installation of above repository, following will do the job.

```
pkg install numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

A work around is to try to install another version of numpy.

Example:

`pip install numpy==1.19.3`